`pyenv` fails in macOS (M3) because compiler cannot create executables
Whenever I ask pyenv to install something, I get some issues that seem to be related to compiling. From the build output:
Installing Python-3.11.9...
python-build: use tcl-tk from homebrew
python-build: use readline from homebrew
python-build: use ncurses from homebrew

BUILD FAILED (OS X 14.5 using python-build 2.4.1-9-gb0cd5bf8)
...
Last 10 log lines:
checking for pkg-config... no
checking for --enable-universalsdk... no
checking for --with-universal-archs... no
checking MACHDEP... "darwin"
checking for gcc... clang
checking whether the C compiler works... no
configure: error: in `/var/folders/zt/pvq3drld4qgd783m1kzh17480000gq/T/python-build.20240605123450.20100/Python-3.11.9':
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details
make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.

I've installed and used pyenv for years, but I set up this computer in a hurry, and I can't figure out what's wrong.
Things I've thought of:

I deleted and reinstalled homebrew
I used homebrew to install all build dependencies
I installed pyenv through a git checkout
I deleted and re-installed Xcode command line tools
brew doctor is happy

What am I missing?

I was also facing similar issue but replacing these lines in .zshrc file fixed this issue for me.
Remove these exports
export PYENV_ROOT="$HOME/.pyenv
export PATH="$PYENV_ROOT/shims:$PATH"
export PATH="$PYENV_ROOT/bin:$PATH
source ~/.zprofile

Export them like this
echo 'export PYENV_ROOT="$HOME/.pyenv"' >> ~/.zprofile
echo 'export PATH="$PYENV_ROOT/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zprofile
echo 'eval "$(pyenv init --path)"' >> ~/.zprofile
echo 'eval "$(pyenv init -)"' >> ~/.zprofile

Once this is done, to make sure the file is loaded, run “source ~/.zshrc” or restart the terminal.
